# sharing in google doc

Tags: google-drive

Someone within the organisation has requested access to my google doc. Every time I open the doc, the request comes up, which is rather annoying as I access this document all the time. Every time I deny the request (by hitting the X). However, each time I open the document, it comes up again. Can this be stopped please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want unknown people to be able to view your Doc? If so, then you have correctly allowed view access via a link. If you only want a handful of people to view the Doc, you should **turn off** the view access via the link, and instead just share the Doc with those people's Google e-mail addresses individually.

You cannot block one person from requesting edit access if you have let others view the Doc with only the link.

If there is conflict, it is best to reach out to the person via the phone, to ask them to not request edit access.

Comment: Thank you. I've asked that person who's email continues to come up when I open the doc. They are not sure why and do not know how to turn this off. Therefore, I've copied the doc and created a new one, sending only to people I've allowed. (It's still weird how the request cannot be turned off). Thank you again.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer (with the tick).

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you are using a link or URL saved in your web browser as a bookmark, as an autocomple entry, etc. to access your document. Instead of doing that, go to

- https://drive.google.com
- https://docs.google.com

then open your document from there.